# Cutting videos with ffmpeg : length not accurate

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I was trying to cut a 5 second longer sengment from a video test.wmv (10 minutes length) starting from 00:03:00 position. So I used the following ffmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00 -t 00:00:05 -i test.wmv -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec copy 1.wmv
```

But it gives me a output wmv that is 11 seconds longer which is twice the duration specified.

What am I doing wrong? Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: The video has to start at a I-frame. That means it might have to start *a lot* earlier than 03:00.

Answer (score 10):

It often happens when using the `-ss` and `-t` together with `-c copy` or `-codec copy`.

Don't use `copy`, and use another codecs or simply don't specify `-c` , `-codec` options. and this won't happen.

for example: `ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00 -t 00:00:05 -i test.wmv -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 1.mp4`

Comment: The video won’t be cut be reencoded, though.

Comment: @DanielB It's not. I mean changing `-vcodec copy` only. but keeping `-ss` and `-t` options.

Comment: Yeah. That implies (part of) the original video stream isn't used as is. Instead, it is decoded and then encoded again, leading to quality loss. Even worse, without specifying additional parameter for the encoder, it might look *a lot* worse.

Comment: @DanielB he wants accurate seeking and for accurate seeking, we have to decode video stream. yeah decode and encoding process cuases quality loss  but that's not too much observable for one cycle. i mean this solution is maybe ok for practical goals.

Comment: This answer is a workaround for the problem. It has been reported as a bug in ffmpeg, but there won't be a fix for a long time. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4905

Comment: @RobinLoxley that ticket seems to be specifically for flac files. It's unlikely that you can't get accurate lengths from any file through something as robust as ffmpeg.

Comment: `-t` produced incorrect length while `-to` solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Place the start and end parameters after the input. That should make it more accurate.

```
ffmpeg -i test.wmv -ss 00:03:00 -to 00:03:05 -c copy 1.wmv
```

The `-t` option means go upto this duration. I used `-to`. So in your case it should be

```
-to 00:03:05
```

Also, I did not change the audio codec from the original. That should work.

Comment: Thanks. The option -to didn't work in my case but I tried with -t and the result was better but not accurate. I got 6.4 seconds long segment this time. Also when I place -ss parameter after input it takes long time to complete

Comment: @EnnFenn It shouldn't be *that* inaccurate. Are you using a somewhat recent version of ffmpeg? (See http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) Can you give us the full, uncut ffmpeg command line output, please? Note that if `-ss` is specified before `-i`, the `-t` and `-to` options [are equivalent](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking%20with%20FFmpeg#Cuttingsmallsections).

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem. It has been a reported bug. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4905

Comment: @RobinLoxley see comment for the other answer. The ticket seems to be specifically for flac files.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the @Rajib guide to construct a query that works perfectly with trimming a video with precise duration/length

```
-i input_path -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:07 -c copy -copyts output_path
```

The additional parameters are to maintain output video quality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).