# Re-Encoding of Video (mp4) to improve cutting accuracy

Tags: video, ffmpeg, fedora, avidemux

I'm trying right now to cut a video which was recorded with the Zoom-App. The results are pretty mixed. Sometimes I'm able to cut exactly, but the last video had a cut divergence of +/- 4 seconds, which is pretty useless.
Switching to avidemux was not a help either. Same result (Marking A-B, Save the Video).

I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00 -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

I have been searching the internet already, applied the solutions, but was not satisfied.
Right now I'd like to try re-encoding the whole video before in order to do clean cuts. What are my options? Or are there other ways? (as apparently avidemux is affected as well)

I would still like to use `-c copy` as with some other options the quality can drop drastically. I'm assuming the keyframes are not set properly, but can only guess.

- [Cutting videos with ffmpeg : length not accurate](https://superuser.com/questions/685562/cutting-videos-with-ffmpeg-length-not-accurate/1131088)
- Moving `-to` right after `-ss` did help indeed, but now I'm stuck again.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re expecting…? If there aren’t appropriate I-frames (full frames) in the stream, it cannot be cut where you want it cut. Not without re-encoding, which implies _not_ using `-c copy`.

Comment: I'm thinking of re-encoding the entire video before, is that actually an option? I just wonder the frames are apparently several seconds apart

Comment: You only need to re-encode the portion you want. If the output quality isn't acceptable, tweak the encoding parameters.

Comment: You would still not necessarily get I-frames at the timestamps you’d need them. // Just to give you some insight: A ~20 minute TV cartoon I have contains only 1006 I-frames among 21267/12014 B/P-frames. Of course, non-moving backgrounds play a large role here.

Comment: @DanielB - understood, but is it possible to solve this issue somehow? File Size, Codec or Speed are not the problem